# Change XML root node using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new in XSLT. I would like to change a root node in XML base on condition of other child node. but keep the child nodes always same. For example, I have following XML:

```
   <Root1>
    ................
    ................

    <Root2>
    ................
    ................

        <AnimalOrPlant>
             <Type>A</Type>
              <Food1>Something</Food1>
              <Food2>Somthing11</Food2>
              <Name>ant</Name>
              <Color>Black</GIIN>
              <Waterconsumption>5lt</Waterconsumption>
        </AnimalOrPlant>  
    ................
    ................

    </Root2>
    ................
    ................
</Root1>
```

I like to change XML to:

```
<Root1>
    ................
    ................
    <Root2>
    ................
    ................
        <Animal>
             <Type>A</Type>
              <Food1>Something</Food1>
              <Food2>Somthing11</Food2>
              <Name>ant</Name>
              <Color>Black</Color>
              <Waterconsumption>5lt</Waterconsumption>
        </Animal>
     ................
    ................ 
    </Root2>
    ................
    ................
</Root1>
```

That means depents on `<type> = A`, I have change node `<AnimalOrPlant>` to `<Animal>`. If the `<Type> = P`, I will change it to `<Plant>`.I have write the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="Root1">
 <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="Root2/AnimalOrPlant/Type='A'">
        <Animal>
            <xsl:element name ="Type">
              <xsl:value-of select="Root2/AnimalOrPlant/Type"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name ="Food1">
              <xsl:value-of select="Root2/AnimalOrPlant/Food1"/>          
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name ="Food2">
              <xsl:value-of select="Root2/AnimalOrPlant/Food2"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name ="Name">
              <xsl:value-of select="<xsl:value-of select="Root2/AnimalOrPlant/Name"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name ="Color">
              <xsl:value-of select="<xsl:value-of select="Root2/AnimalOrPlant/Color"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name ="Waterconsumption">
              <xsl:value-of select="<xsl:value-of select="Root2/AnimalOrPlant/Waterconsumption"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </Animal>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="Root2/AnimalOrPlant/Type='P'">
        <Plant>
            <xsl:element name ="Type">
              <xsl:value-of select="Root2/AnimalOrPlant/Type"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name ="Food1">
              <xsl:value-of select="Root2/AnimalOrPlant/Food1"/>          
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name ="Food2">
              <xsl:value-of select="Root2/AnimalOrPlant/Food2"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name ="Name">
              <xsl:value-of select="<xsl:value-of select="Root2/AnimalOrPlant/Name"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name ="Color">
              <xsl:value-of select="<xsl:value-of select="Root2/AnimalOrPlant/Color"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name ="Waterconsumption">
              <xsl:value-of select="<xsl:value-of select="Root2/AnimalOrPlant/Waterconsumption"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </Plant>
    </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>   
</xsl:template>
```

I don't want to repeat the child nodes in every `<when>` condition. Because there will be several different types. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="AnimalOrPlant">
    <xsl:variable name="name">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Type='A'">Animal</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="Type='P'">Plant</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>Unknown</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{$name}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note: This has nothing to do with the *root node* or even with the *root element*.

Comment: Thanks michael, I am getting this error.'xsl:template' cannot be a child of the 'Root2' element. Because i am using 'xsl:template' in root2 for some other item. Can I use multi xsl:template in same XSLT?

Comment: @Shuvra Templates cannot be nested. If you have a template matching `Root2`, place it alongside the other templates and makes sure it contains a suitable `xsl:apply-templates` instruction to pass the context to the template matching `AnimalOrPlant`.

Answer (score 0):

This is straight-forward, if you learn about the [XSLT identity template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This copies all existing nodes in your XML, so you only have to worry about the nodes you want to change. You just write templates to match these ones. For example, to turn the `AnimalOrPlant` elements, with `Type` of A, into the `Animal` ones, do this:

```
<xsl:template match="AnimalOrPlant[Type='A']">
    <Animal>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </Animal>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="AnimalOrPlant[Type='A']">
        <Animal>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </Animal>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="AnimalOrPlant[Type='P']">
        <Plant>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </Plant>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I have other Nodes in <root1>and <Root2> also. What I want is to create <Animal> and <plant> dynamically.

Comment: The identity template takes care of all the other nodes.

Comment: I am getting this error.'xsl:template' cannot be a child of the 'Root2' element. Because i am using 'xsl:template' in root2 for some other item.

Comment: Can i use multiple xsl:template in same XSLT?

Comment: You can see the XSLT above in action at http://xsltransform.net/bnnZWB. It sounds like you have copied just a single template from the answer, and added it to the wrong place in your XSLT. You should really use the whole stylesheet in place of what you are currently using. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Tim, I manage to work out.  I have use the <xsl:variable> and instead of apply <xsl:apply-templates/> I have copied the nodes those are repeating.